# How to properly implement DbCommandInterceptor with per-DbContext state?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging, entity-framework-6, interceptor

I am following Tom Dykstra's [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial.  [Part 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/connection-resiliency-and-command-interception-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) of this tutorial covers EF6's connection resiliency and command interception features.

As a way of demonstrating the use of command interception, the tutorial provides two example [`DbCommandInterceptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbcommandinterceptor.aspx) implementations.  One (`SchoolInterceptorLogging`) interfaces with a logger to record each SQL command that is executed, how much time it took to execute, and whether there was an exception.  The other example (`SchoolInterceptorTransientErrors`) simulates transient DB errors so that connection resiliency can be tested.

Although the tutorial does not specifically mention the issue of synchronization, I assume that because a single instance of the `DbCommandInterceptor` is registered via [`DbInterception.Add()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbinterception.add.aspx), that any per-[`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.aspx) state utilized by the `DbCommandInterceptor` must be synchronized.  For example, `SchoolInterceptorLogging` should probably synchronize use of the `_stopwatch`, and `SchoolInterceptorTransientErrors` should probably synchronize the `_counter`.

I thought about using thread-local storage via [`ThreadStaticAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute.aspx) or [`ThreadLocal<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx).  However, I am not sure that this is sufficient.  Suppose that my application uses [`DbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.savechangesasync.aspx) to asynchronously save all changes.  Isn't it possible for the same thread to handle two asynchronous save operations?  If so, then thread-local storage wouldn't work.

Another idea is to [store per-`DbContext` state in the call context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6896652/196844).  However, when using the `CallContext`, it is recommended that only immutable types should be used.  (See Stephen Cleary's blog post, [Implicit Async Context ("AsyncLocal")](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html).)

A third idea is to use a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) where the keys are the [`DbCommandInterceptionContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.interception.dbcommandinterceptioncontext.aspx) object passed to NonQueryExecuting()/NonQueryExecuted(), ReaderExecuting()/ReaderExecuted(), or ScalarExecuting()/ScalarExecuted(), and the values are a state object.  However, I have two questions about this approach:

- Is the `DbCommandInterceptionContext` object that is passed to the `*Executing()`/`*Executed()` method distinct for each save operation?

  From setting a breakpoint in `ReaderExecuting()` and calling `GetHashCode()` on the interception context object, it appears to be distinct for each *retry* let alone save operation (tested EntityFramework version 6.1.3).
- Will the `*Executed()` method always be called?

  This is to make sure that anything added to the `ConcurrentDictionary` in the `*Executing()` method can always be cleaned up by the `*Executed()` method.

So, how should a `DbCommandInterceptor` with per-`DbContext` state be implemented?

Comment: I am wondering if you found a solution to this problem. I was searching around for an answer as well, and found it odd that there was no per-DbContext hook I could find. My use case is wanting a "read uncommited"-only DbContext and a read-write DbContext.

Comment: @JohnZabroski: Unfortunately, I did not find an answer to this.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to steal the connection string used for the DbConext object, and hash it to decide whether or not to apply context changes. Or some similar "tramp parameter" global variable trick like this